# Property does not exist on type 'JestMatchers '

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, cypress, chai

I'm working with an app where I want to have installed jest and cypress for testing purposes. I have my jest test that run ok and everything is fine with that, then I installed cypress by executing this command

```
 yarn add cypress @cypress/react @cypress/webpack-dev-server
```

And I have my test in Cypress that runs ok whenever I try them using

```
yarn cypress open-ct
```

But the thing is, that Chai assertions works well in the test but show errors in my IDE

My dummy test

```
it('Test test and onClick', () => {
  let clicked = false
  const onClick = () => (clicked = true)
  mount(<Button text="Random text" onClick={onClick} />)

  cy.get('button').should('have.text', 'Random text')
  cy.get('button')
    .click()
    .then(() => {
      expect(clicked).to.equal(clicked)
    })
})
```

and the error shown:

[image: error shown]

I have tried to follow some guides I saw on the Internet but I'm missing something because my IDE (Webstorm or Visual Studio) only suggests me Jest assertions not Chai's, and if I use Jest assertion I got this error while running Cypress

Changing the test assertion to this:

```
expect(clicked).toEqual(clicked)
```

shows this error:

[image]

I don't really care if I have to use Jest or Chai assertions as long as this works. My preference will be Chai's because are the ones that works within Cypress, but right now, I only wanted that to don't show an error in my IDE or in Cypress.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use the Chai assertions because the Cypress tests _aren't run with Jest_. That also means you need to configure TypeScript accordingly, to tell it those files should have the same library types as the other tests. Have a look at https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I try creating a tsconfig.json in my cypress folder as suggested here https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Configure-tsconfig-json, restarted TS server, IDE and even my computer but still doesn't work

Comment: Without a [mre] it's hard to say what the issue with your config is. It works fine in this kit I put together, for example: https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit-ts.

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe for spending your time with this typescript newbie :)

I have fixed it by installing chai and mocha dependencies with `yarn add --dev chai mocha ts-node @types/chai @types/mocha` and adding this to my cypress test file `
import { expect } from 'chai'`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank you @jonrsharpe for spending your time with this typescript newbie :)

I have fixed it by installing chai and mocha dependencies with `yarn add --dev chai mocha ts-node @types/chai @types/mocha` and adding this to my cypress test file `import { expect } from 'chai'`

Comment: Perhaps there is an alternative solution as it appears to be a bit hacky.